# How to use secret in pull_request_review similar to pull_request_target?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am having an issue where external contributors can't use my action on my repo because the `pull_request_review` considers the forked repo and that repo doesn't have the secret defined. One thing that would be great is if I could set a secret in the action's source repo and then use that secret when it runs. Is there a way to do this?

## Edit

I have solved this issue, the above was trying to use the key in the action repo itself, but that didn't work. It's also generally not very secure to do that. But at it's core I wanted the same behavior associated with `pull_request_target` but with `pull_request_review` (@github please add `pull_request_review_target`).

I have provided a work-around that I used in my answer below, there may be better alternatives, but it worked for me and generally seems secure and reliable (although still a hack so @github...)

I updated the title of this question to help clarify the question and its relevance to my solution.

Comment: Take a look at this, it might help: https://github.blog/2020-08-03-github-actions-improvements-for-fork-and-pull-request-workflows/ It is possible to send secrets to workflow from fork pull requests, but only for private repositories.

Comment: huh, unfortunately the repo is not private. Do you know if there are any plans to have a pull_request_review_target event or a way to use the workflow_run to re-run a workflow?

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: pull_request_review -> dummy_workflow -> workflow_run trigger -> actual_action_call -> retrieve original PR info

To get around this `pull_request_review` limitiation I created a dummy workflow that triggers a `workflow_run` workflow which then calls the action. This somewhat complicates things because in the case of using the `workflow_run` action you must then retrieve the triggering pr somehow. This wasn't too challenging, and I have attached a method called `requirePRFromWorkflowRun` which returns the pr associated with a workflow id.

#### Dummy workflow (triggered on a PR)

```yaml
on: 
  pull_request_review:
    types: [submitted]
name: <NAME>
jobs:
  dummy-workflow:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: dummy workflow
    steps:
      - name: Explanation
        run: echo "this is a dummy workflow that triggers a workflow_run; it's necessary because otherwise the repo secrets will not be in scope for externally forked pull requests"
```

#### workflow_run workflow (in-scope of root repo secrets)

You can either use your own or you can use mine (for simplicity I chose not to publish this on the marketplace, but the code is open source)

```yaml
name: Workflow run re-run auto-merge-bot on review
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows:
      - <NAME OF DUMMY ACTION>

jobs:
  rerun:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Rerun Desired Action
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Node.js Environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - name: run desired action
        uses: ethereum/EIP-Bot@d41fda65e1d311ce82b85f2e8db3fdbd5965acf5
        id: rerun-desired-action
        with:
          # needs write access to the repo
          GITHUB-TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
          WORKFLOW-ID: ${{github.event.workflow_run.id}}
          # the event type you wish to rerun
          EVENT-TYPE: "pull_request_target"
          # the id of the workflow you're trying to re-run
          ID-TO-RERUN: "6519819"
```

Comment: Hi @Alita, I have exactly the same problem, but I don't fully understand your `workflow_run` workflow, nor where the mentioned `requirePRFromWorkflowRun` method is defined.

Comment: hey, checkout the repo https://github.com/ethereum/EIP-Bot/tree/rerun-pull-request-target-on-review which is just a branch on the EIP-Bot repo. This is the code that's being used on my implementation. the `workflow_run` workflow is triggered because of the dummy. The dummy is not in context of the repo (only fork) but the workflow_run is so it uses the dummy (triggered by pr) that's out of scope of the key to a workflow_run that's triggered by the dummy and the workflow_run has access to the key. The requirePRFromWorkflowRun retrieves the PR that triggered the initial dummy thus complete